# DDD: Confusion about repository/domain boundaries

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

My domain consists of Products, Departments, Classes, Manufacturers, DailySales, HourlySales.

I have a ProductRepository which facilitates storing/retrieving products from storage.

I have a DepartmentAndClass repository which facilitates storing/retrieving of departments and classes, as well as adding and removing products from those departments and classes.

I also have a DailySales repository which I use to retrieve statistics about daily sales from multiple groupings. ie..

```
DailySales.GetSalesByDepartment(dateTime)
DailySales.GetSalesByClass(dateTime)
DailySales.GetSalesByHour(dateTime)
```

Is it correct to have these sales tracking methods in their own repository like this? Am I on the right track?

Comment: It makes sense to me. You can change the naming of the methods to make it more expressive, like DailySales.ByClass(...)
See this article for more helpful info about this: http://philcalcado.com/2010/12/23/how-to-write-a-repository/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since domains are so dependent on context some answers are harder than others.  I would, however, place statistics on the `Query` side of things.  You probably do not want to be calculating those stats on the fly as you will be placing some heavy processing on your database.  Typically the stats should be denormalized for quick access where only filtering is required.

You may want to take a look at CQRS if you haven't done so.

Comment: I can tell you that in the project i'm working on we already do a little bit of this. For instance rather than calculate daily sales on the fly every time, we actually keep a "running total" of daily sales broken down by department, group etc inside a separate table. I believe this is more or less what you mean? It's the DailySales repository which is querying this denormalized data. That's what my question is about. I'm just finding it hard to learn the "correct way" of doing things in this DDD world.

Comment: It's really the naming conventions as well as locations of classes that stumps me, rather than the concepts themselves. Should a class which queries this denormalized data be called a Repository, or should it be called a Query? DailySalesRepository / DailySalesQuery. Should the class live inside the data layer along with the repositories? Should there be an interface for DailySalesQuery which lives inside the infrastructure assembly, allowing for future changes to the underlying database.. etc.. It's those sorts of questions which are really nagging me.

Comment: It really is more of a query.  Other than calculating the statistics you really have no need of a fully fledged class since it will merely act as a data container.  Well, you *could* have that if you want.  The point is that such as class is more-or-less meaningless in a DDD sense since it is not an Entity.  It doesn't have a life-cycle representing some unique *thing* in your business.  It is simply a result. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Although most queries return an object or a collection of objects, it also fits within the concept to return some types of summary calculations, such as an object count, or a sum of a numerical attribute that was intended by the model to be tallied.
>
> ```
>     Eric Evans - Domain-Driven Design
> ```

This might be considered a [read model](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). Are these daily sales objects being used in any domain model behaviour? Does any business logic depend on them? If not, it might be a good idea to separate this out into a distinct read model - at which point you're taking your first steps into [CQRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).